# create Custom menu bar Text as well as Icon Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an Android application, I want to TextView with icon in our menu bar list but when i try to show on toolbar , these icon shows on toolbar but not show in menu list with text.

But I need to text with icon like that

[image]

Comment: Post your Xml code in question

Comment: no xml code but i want to know a way for implmented....i know another way is open dialog on top right. But you have another solotion for creating this menu ..